# How to create a time series in Grafana for Clickhouse server available disk space?

Tags: grafana, clickhouse

I'm trying to create a time series for free space in Clickhouse. I've found a table in CH that stores the needed information - system.disks.
The problem is, this table doesn't store history data, it only stores momentary data. And I need to build a time series. So how can I make it?

Comment: First of all, this is in no way about programming, so off-topic here.

Comment: But here's a general overview: you need to store your data somewhere. It can be Clickhouse itself, Prometheus or any other time series storage (or DBMS). And you need process that will store current state into your storage: job in dbms, custom app, or Prometheus can do this by itself (through appropriate exporter of course)

Answer (score 0):

You could create a Materialized View on the `system.disks` table. Every time a new row is entered in `system.disks`, it would be inserted into your MV as well:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW free_space 
ENGINE = MergeTree
PRIMARY KEY timestamp
POPULATE AS
SELECT
    now() AS timestamp,
    name,
    path,
    free_space
FROM system.disks;
```